# Angular Material matautocomplete actually select the value

Tags: angular, forms, angular-material

I am running into a problem where form is not selecting the value once autofilled.

It does autofill the state but it doesn't seem like it was selected since I am getting form is invalid when using [Validators.required].

Wanted to know if there is way to actually select the input value.

[image]

component.html

```
       <mat-form-field>
             <input type="text" placeholder="State" matInput formControlName="state"
            [matAutocomplete]="auto" required>
                <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" dropdown-arrow="true" (optionSelected)="state.name">
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let state of states" [value]="state.name">{{state.name}}</mat-option>
                </mat-autocomplete> 
        </mat-form-field>
```

component.ts

```
    this.shippingForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        userName: [''],
        password: [''],
        firstName: ['', [Validators.required]],
        lastName: ['', [Validators.required]],
        address1: [],
        address2: [],
        city: [, [Validators.required]],
        country: ['',  [Validators.required]],
        postalCode: [,  [Validators.required]],
        state: [,  [Validators.required]],
        phone: [,  [Validators.required]],
        email: [,  [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
    });
```

Comment: can you post your validator?

Comment: @AnyMoose I have added the validator.  Thank

Comment: maybe a copy of this issue... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44668289/angularjs-form-validation-failing-when-input-populated-dynamic/44668740

Comment: What do you mean by 'autofill'? Do you mean populate the value without user entry (i.e. in code)? Show that code.

Comment: Sorry wasn't specific enough.  Autofill by like using chrome to generate input field. So once you click firstName it will autofill all the form input for you.  It does fill the option field but when I submit that the input that contains option value is null.

Answer (score 0):

```
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" dropdown-arrow="true" (optionSelected)="getStateName($event.option.value)">
```

Call a function on `optionSelect()` and try see what's the value in either `console.log()` or `alert()`. Once, we have the value coming, it can be manipulated further

Comment: Ok looks like it prints value when the select option is clicked.  But when using autofill it just fills the value but doesn't seem to actually select the value since I am not getting anything printed doing that way.

Comment: if its able to print the value of the option then this value could be assigned to a component private variable

Comment: Yeah.  If I select it manually it will print the value.  But if I am going to autofill from the start it does not print.  So not sure if there is way to automatically select when using autofill.

Comment: Yes i believe thats how material autocompletes are stuctured and implemented visit https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/examples @Yh1234